# MSDN website not loading layout

Tags: networking, website

When I visit the MSDN website ([msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com)) in the morning everything loads like normal. When I visit the site in the afternoon, the layout for the page does not load. All of the text and links appear, but none of the side layout or panels or colors appear. It makes the site very difficult to look through for code examples. Outside of our local network, it works fine. I can load the site on my phone like normal. When I load the site over Wifi on the local network on my phone, it does not work.

Does anyone have any ideas why the site will sometimes load and sometimes won't?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Could you possibly provide a screen shot of when it's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because it isn't loading the CSS (and possibly some Javascript) file for the site.

This is typically due to a slow or congested local network or Internet connection so if you are doing this from your work, you should complain to your IT department.

Generally, doing a ctrl-f5 will force a full reload of the page (clearing the cache) and, if it can get all the data back in time, it should work.